# Macro to define a type

Tags: c++, c++11, build

Is there a way in C++ to define a type based on a preprocessor flag? I have two versions of a library, one that is native and one that is built on the top of [thirft](https://thrift.apache.org/).

Both versions have exactly the same function signatures, except the return and argument types. The native versions passes pointers of objects around, while the thirft version uses i64 to represent the pointers.

I was wondering if there is a way for be to build a project that would use any of the libraries based on a compilation flag. So for example:

```
//native
AType* obj = fun(AnotherType* another_obj)

//thirft
i64 obj = fun(i64 another_obj)
```

I was wondering if there is a construct sort of like this:

```
if native
    X is Atype*
    Y is AnotherType*
else
    X is i64
    Y is i64
end

//native
X obj = fun(Y another_obj)

//thirft
X obj = fun(Y another_obj)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If both versions are able to compile with the same known data (so you are not actually not defining `AnotherType` in the version that doesn't use it, but just have different function signatures) then you can use [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
using ActualType = std::conditional<IS_NATIVE, i64, AnotherType>::type;
```

Otherwise you have to stick to retro `#if #else #endif` macros.

Answer (score 4):

You want something like:

```
#ifdef native
    typedef Atype* X
    typedef AnotherType* Y
#else
    typedef i64 X
    typedef i64 Y
#endif
```

If `native` is always set (to a non-zero or zero value), you can use `#if native` instead.